# Resolve promises React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to do a series of dispatch actions before going to the homescreen.

I felt that promises might be the correct approach for this, but using the following code we go down the code and change the screen BEFORE we have completed each of the functions (autoLogin, tickets, contacts, alerts, partners). How can I ensure that I have completed those 5 before the last resetNavigation command?

```
Promise.resolve ( this.store.dispatch(autoLogin())  )
 .then(function (response) {
   store.dispatch(tickets());
 })
 .then(function (response) {
   store.dispatch(contacts());
 })
 .then(function (response) {
   store.dispatch(alerts());
 })
 .then(function (response) {
   store.dispatch(partners());
 })
 .then(function (response) {
   this.resetNavigation('HomeScreen');
 })
```

Comment: You need redux thunk middleware

Comment: Are functions like `tickets()` usual redux dispatches, or are they async functions like thunks?

Comment: Redux dispatches

Comment: If they are regular dispatches, then can't you simply run them in order? They aren't async.

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch an action to navigate again inside shouldComponentUpdate() method of which partners action effect in your components.And . To give an example of that:

```
class ComponentEffectedByPartnerAction {
     shouldComponentUpdate(){
       this.resetNavigation('HomeScreen');
     }
}
```

And delete last step of your promise

```
Promise.resolve ( this.store.dispatch(autoLogin())  )
 .then(function (response) {
   store.dispatch(tickets());
 })
 .then(function (response) {
   store.dispatch(contacts());
 })
 .then(function (response) {
   store.dispatch(alerts());
 })
 .then(function (response) {
   store.dispatch(partners());
 })
 .then(function (response) {
   console.log("last chance")
   //this.resetNavigation('HomeScreen');
 })
```